# Null terminated char phrasing in file format specification

Tags: java, c++, c

I'm writing a Java codec for an old(ish), but still relevant scientific [file format](http://serswiki.bme.gatech.edu/images/a/ae/SPC_Open_Specification.pdf).  A C Header is given in the reference document, but I'm coming up short on the number of bytes processed by the time I get to a particular variable.  I'm pretty sure everything is fine up until the following lines:

```
b = new byte[9];
in.readFully(b);
this.fres = new String(b); //37-45
b = new byte[9];
in.readFully(b);
this.fsource = new String(b);
this.fpeakpt = in.readUnsignedShort(); //46-54
//this.fpeakpt = in.readUnsignedShort();
b = new byte[4];
this.fspare = new Float[8]; //55-86
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    in.readFully(b);
    this.fspare[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getFloat();
}
b = new byte[130];
in.readFully(b);
this.fcmnt = new String(b);//87-216
```

The numbers in comments are the number of bytes read since the beginning of the file.  Unfortunately, the reference is a C header file, so I'm not 100% sure on how many bytes are to be read for each of the variables due to my lack of substantial C experience.  The following is taken from the reference:

```
char  fres[9]; /* Resolution description text (null terminated) */
char  fsource[9]; /* Source instrumentdescription text (null terminated) */
WORD  fpeakpt; /* Peak point number for interferograms (0=not known) */
float  fspare[8]; /* Used for Array Basic storage */
char  fcmnt[130]; /* Null terminated comment ASCII text string */
```

fres appears to be ok when debugged - the string it is read to starts with an actual character and ends with an extra space and contains sensible information.  However, the fcmnt string has 4 extra spaces before any text and total bytes read is off by 4 bytes by the end of my code. One question I have is whether readUnsignedShort reads the same number of bytes as a WORD.  Was a WORD 4 bytes in 1996?  Everything I've read suggests it was.

Any ideas?

Here is a hexdump of the only test file I have gotten my hands on so far.  As you can see, it's not very helpful in determining the problem with all the nulls.

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  00 4B 00 02 32 07 00 00 00 00 00 80 15 41 AF 40  .K..2......€.A¯@
00000010  FF FF FF FF F1 16 7C 40 01 00 00 00 01 02 00 00  ÿÿÿÿñ.|@........
00000020  B6 23 83 7C 34 2E 30 20 43 4D 2D 31 00 00 00 00  ¶#ƒ|4.0 CM-1....
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 65 78 74 67 6F 65 73  ........Textgoes
00000060  68 65 72 65 74 65 78 74 67 6F 65 73 68 65 72 65  heretextgoeshere
00000070  74 65 78 74 67 6F 65 73 68 65 72 65 00 00 00 00  textgoeshere....
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000A0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000B0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000C0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000D0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
etc. the nulls continue for awhile
```

Comment: arrays of 9 bytes are pretty weird.

Comment: The width of a word is based on the width of a char, right?

Comment: I'd go with [WORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx) as being an unsigned 16-bit integer.  Looks like old Windows code to me.

Comment: Then I'm stuck as to where the missing bytes are :(  readUnsignedShort reads 16 bits.

Why are 9 byte arrays weird?  They are meant to be "strings".

Comment: Could you post a hexdump for the 1st 150 bytes?

Comment: @user1101373: 9 byte arrays are weird because they cause other items to start on odd address. on most machines only single bytes (or byte arrays) can start on odd address, at least if you want efficiency. this is called "alignment" (at the hardware level it has to do with how memory locations are selected). on the other hand, in the layout you show there are two such arrays in succession. still weird.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Thanks for the explanation.  That is a bit odd.

Comment: @alk, I added a modified hexdump (modified the text to obfiscate its origins).  I'm guessing you wanted to look for clues in the bytes of interest.  It's too bad that they're all null.  I still need to get my hands on test files of a different type, but they tend to be confidential or hard to find.

Comment: In C, arrays (especially arrays of `char`) are usually null-terminated. It is possible that the source file hardcoded each of those strings as eight bytes, and that the C code which read it allocated an extra byte at the end of the array for the terminating NUL. If that's the case, you should try reading eight bytes into each of those arrays and not nine.

Comment: FWIW, the link to the source specification appears to be broken.

Comment: For the hex dump shown `WORD` being 2 bytes make sense to me: The text starzs at 0x58. 0x58 - 8*4 (`fspare`) - 2 (`fpeakpt`) - 9 (`fsource`) - 9 (`fres`) = 36. At Offset 36 there is ASCII info: `4.0...`. This suits.

Comment: @qwrrty, If I read 8 bytes, I end up even shorter than I am now and as alk pointed out, the math works out to give me ASCII text with 9 bytes.
It's strange that the two sources of this specification that I knew of went down today.  That can't be a coincidence.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood by which direction you were off in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as a 36-byte file header before the first value in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right trail.

The number of bytes in the types of different languages are different and often unhelpfully defined in terms like "a short is at least X number of bytes and not larger than an int".

I am no c-expert either but I think the problem is you are using Java to read in a data type which was defined in c and what you're getting is the size in bytes that Java has defined a short to be, not the size in bytes that the original c programmer understood it to be.

You have to harmonize the expectations of the c-header in terms of byte count with the reality of what Java thinks about type-sizes (byte-counts for different types).

It's a little confusing. Do you have a ton of old data that needs to now be processed by a Java program and that data is binary? If that's the issue then you have to make Java decode the bytes of the file as they were written by c and you can't use the "readShort readInt" methods Java provides since they'll read too many or too few bytes.

You have some expectations about how many bytes you should have read at different points in the program which indicates to me you're reading a stream of bytes written by C into a  Java program.

I am not aware of any library that will compensate for the difference; you're going to have to read the file byte by byte and assemble the expectd data values from those bytes using custom code, armed with knowledge of how many bytes were in a short for the c implementation used to create the data.

Glad I'm not you :)

Very best of luck anyways!!!!

edit: also, this:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

Basically, if you have an file of bytes and you don't know what the encoding was on it, you have to use the scientific method to arrive at a best guess. Guess the number of bytes of the next data type, translate to your current encoding, look at the result and see if it's plausible. Rinse and repeat.